# Copy/pasting QGIS features between two layers with linestringZ() geometry gives linestring()

Tags: qgis, linestring

I'm puzzled: when I copy-paste a feature with `linestringz()` geometry to another layer I get `linestring(`) and the elevation attribute is lost. Although when I paste to a text editor I see a `linestringz()`. Can anybody please tell why I see this behavior? Addendum: both layers have `linestringz()` geometry type. The file I'm copying to, is saved as geojson.

Answer (score 2):

Both layers must be the same type.
[image: zpolygon]

As you can see, one layer is MultiPoligon and second is MultiPoligonZ. 
I assume this may be the reason.

Comment: As said in the title: both Layers (saved as geojson files) have linestringz() geometries!

Comment: my shame, I double checked and they weren't same geom type.. Thanks!

Comment: ...there's still a poblem - obviously it has to do with the json format of my layer.. I've safed my file as geojson, with "include z-values" ticked in the "save features as" dialog. When I look at the source properties of the json, it says geom is linestring, although I did save with Z.. So, when I use this layer and paste linestringz() geometries from an sqlite layer, the z-values get lost.. I've a virtual field in the target layer that outputs the wkt-strings, and after the paste I get a linestring() wkt instead of linestringz(). When I paste the same to a text editor I get linestringz()..